# How can implement the custom url mapping in magento?

Tags: php, magento, routes, url-routing, magento-1.8

I have a custom controller in my module

For example Module name is MyNameSpace_MyModule and Controller name is Seller

This is the URL what i want

sitename/mymodule/textiles

instead of

sitename/mymodule/seller

How can i map the controller like this ?

i mean that

calling is`<?php echo $this->getUrl('mymodulename/seller/index'); ?>`

then the output needs to be **href="site/textiles/"**

Comment: Why not simply name your controller `textiles`?

Comment: No..it is a general coding..i want to reuse this code in several industry. I mean Textiles, Restaurants,ect.... I hope you understand.

Comment: IN this case you need a custom router. Here is a nice example provided by Inchoo about how you can create such a custom router: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-router-in-magento/

Comment: You cannot do it like that. You need to create a method in a helper somewhere. Something like `getTextilesUrl` that is a wrapper for `<?php echo $this->getUrl('mymodulename/textiles'); ?>`. If you decide to change the url later you just have to edit this method.

Comment: Yes, thank you @Marius, I have created a method in Helper Class